# Inverse function theorem /local inverse

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, inverse-function, jacobian

Let $T: {\mathbb{R}}^{n} \rightarrow {\mathbb{R}}^{n}$ be a continuous, linear and bijective mapping and let $f(\vec{x})$ be a continuously differentiable function, such that
$$ \exists C > 0, \forall \vec{x} \in {\mathbb{R}}^{n}, ||f(\vec{x})|| \leq C|| \vec{x} ||^{2}$$
show that
$$g(\vec{x}) : {\mathbb{R}}^{n} \rightarrow {\mathbb{R}}^{n}$$

with

$$ g(\vec{x}) = T\vec{x} + f(\vec{x})$$ has a continuously differentiable inverse mapping in a neighborhood of $\vec{0}$.

———

I think I need to show that the Jacobian of g(x) is regular, but how can I show that exactly and how to go on from there?

The Jacobian of $g(x)$ =

$$\begin{pmatrix} T_{11} + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} &\dots &T_{1n} + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n} \\
\vdots & \vdots &  \vdots \\
T_{n1} + \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1} &\dots &T_{nn} + \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_n} \end{pmatrix}$$

edit:
From the definition of the function it follows that $f(0)=0$, so also $(0)=0$
so does this mean that all the partial derivatives vanish from the above written jacobian? and only the derivatives of T, but how to show that the jacobian does not vanish?

Comment: THe statement is false; just take $f=-T$, then $g=0$

Comment: @peek-a-boo, I had a small typo im the post, I forgot the square, but now the statement is correct, right?

Comment: yes, now it's right. So, what is the derivative of $g$ (just use the sum rule)?

Comment: @peek-a-boo: I have edited,  what I think the gradient is , in the post

Comment: ok, you're getting there. What I was expecting you to say is simply $Dg_0= DT_0+Df_0=T+Df_0$ (i.e derivative of a sum is sum of derivatives, where the second equal sign uses the fact $T$ is a linear transformation). My next question to you is, how do you prove, given your hypotheses, that (i) the function $f$ is differentiable at the origin, and (ii) how do you calculate the derivative; i.e what is $Df_0$ (or what are the entries $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x^j}(0)$)? Just use the definition of differentiability to answer this.

Comment: Just for future reference, linear in this case always implies continuous. More generally for $\mathbb K^n\to\mathbb K^m$ where $\mathbb K=\mathbb R,$ or $\mathbb C,$ and the space is given the usual topology.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: thank you

Comment: @peek-a-boo: but doesn't that follow from the defintion of the function $f$? because we already know that it is continuously differentiable, hence also at the origin? but I do not know how to calculate $D f_0$

Comment: oh my bad i missed that part. If you don't know how to calculate $Df_0$ then go back to the definition of derivatives.

Comment: From the definition of $f$ it follows that $f(0)=0$, and I think I could show that $Df(0)=0$, so does this mean that all the partial derivatives vanish from the above written jacobian?

Comment: I think only the derivatives of $T$ would stay in the jacobian, but how to show that the determinant is not zero there?

Comment: @galaxy-- ok assuming you manage to prove $Df_0=0$, then you're done. $Dg_0=T+Df_0=T+0=T$. What is your given assumption on $T$? Therefore...

Comment: @peek-a-boo: first of all thank you so much for your help, secondly since it is a linear map, would it be T everywhere?

Comment: If you mean is $DT_x=T$ for every $x$, then yes, this is simply by definition of differentiability and linearity of $T$. But if you're asking if $Dg_x=T$ everywhere, then the answer is not-necessarily, in general we have $Dg_x=DT_x+Df_x=T+Df_x$, but from our assumptions, we only know $Df_0=0$.